# jQuery issue when <div> is collapsed

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Website located here:

http://acs.graphicsmayhem.com/spoogs/index.php

Code is located here:  http://jsfiddle.net/vMM8Q/ (website for the calendar blocks uses ids instead of classes, not that it matters any)

So the problem I'm facing is that when you collapse either the top-right or top-left Calendars in the first link, and than reload the page, since it's being cached, it stays collapsed (which is fine).  But when you expand it, it expands all of the way, and doesn't stop until every `<li>` within the `<ul>` are loaded in height, BUT the real kicker is that it shows absolutely nothing!!!  A Big Blank height of nothing!!

It's using display: none; for the CSS of the style of the OVERALL div tag that holds everything in the block (when it's collapsed and toggles this via JS when the - and + are clicked on).  So, even if I assign it a height, it doesn't show anything in there.  All of the variables are assigned to the value of 0 (which doesn't make sense to me).  Is there something that can be done via jQuery to fix this?  If I give it a height, than the calendar months aren't going to fit perfectly, because the height is based off of the content in there and should be.  So defining a height could mess it up, however, not defining a height causes the huge empty space when expanding the block after having been collapsed (after reload of page ofcourse).  Hitting Previous/Next links does absolutely nothing (or so it seems), and nothing gets shown where the calendar month is supposed to be.  arggg...

Is this a known issue in jQuery, that it doesn't perform correctly within div tags that have a display: none; assigned to them?  If so, is there anything that can be done about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem.  For some reason jQuery was not returning a proper `outerWidth` or `outerHeight` on the `<li>` tags or the `<ul>` tags either.  It was returning them as being a value of 0.  When this was clearly not the case.  However, because the surrounding  tag was set to `display: none;` this made it impossible for jQuery to calculate the width/height of the object (including margins), so I just used NUMBERS instead of using outerWidth/outerHeight and that fixed the problem for sure.

Cheers :)